# Pypi.org blocked from command prompt Windows. Pip install does not work

Tags: python-3.x

Access to pypi.org is blocked for me from the command prompt. Using the browser I can reach the domain just fine.

This causes `pip install jupyterlab-lsp` to fail from the command prompt.

Normally I could download the .whl file from Pypi, and install it from local. But this is not available for this package:

https://pypi.org/project/jupyter-lsp/#files

Any alternatives to install the package?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This actually had to do with:
[pip install fails with "connection error: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:598)"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25981703/pip-install-fails-with-connection-error-ssl-certificate-verify-failed-certi)

For Conda you can use the --insecure flag.